# How do can you tell if your cat is hurting?

Tags: cats, play

I have 2 cats around the same age as each other, but sometimes their play gets a bit too rough, and my sisters cat (the elder one) will hurt the younger, and he will get cuts that bleed. Is my cat really hurting, or is it just a shallow cut, and what should i do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cats hide pain](http://healthypets.mercola.com/sites/healthypets/archive/2012/02/03/how-to-know-if-your-cat-is-in-pain-and-what-to-do-about-it.aspx).  It's instinctive.  The cat that shows pain, in the wild, is the cat the predators attack first.  Being that cat is not a good survival strategy.  In fact, if a cat is showing outward signs of pain, it can be an indication it has given up, or that the pain is *extremely* serious- in either case, get to the vet.

If the cat is not showing pain, it is really hard to know whether it actually is feeling pain.  Treat the wound like you would for a child that came in from playing in the yard crying because he fell and skinned his elbow.  If the cat will let you, that is.  Do your best to determine the severity by spreading the fur and seeing the length and depth of the cut.  Apply direct pressure with a (non-adhesive) gauze pad until the bleeding is completely stopped.

As always, when in doubt- vet.

Comment: Also be aware that skin heal quickly on cats, which can be a bad thing: the skin can heal before the underlying injury, which forms an abscess. So watch out for tenderness on wounds that appear to have healed.

Comment: Should note while cats hide ongoing pain, cats will react to immediate injury, usually with a hiss, angry meow, or by swatting and/or biting.  If the cat doesn't seem particularly defensive of getting cut, probably the cut is not too serious, but as stated, use your own judgement.

Answer (score -2):

They will meow a lot and be extra laying have to cats who hurt them self's all the time if they look and act hurt call a vet ASAP

Comment: this is wrong,a cat that have been hurt will try to hide itself and stay quiet so if your cat starts to hide more than normal you might consider a trip to the vet.